# PHP Mailer & issue with spacing in html send out in Gmail only

Tags: email, formatting, gmail, phpmailer

I have a simple PHPMailer script that grabs some HTML from a database row and then sends an email using this html as the body (a basic newsletter script)

Everything seems ok except with Gmail which seems to break up this string in random places, occasionally this breaks a valid HTML tag causing the page formatting to look slightly screwed up in gmail (but ok in Outlook)

For instance.. the line below is part of a CSS inline-style which has broken the word solid and placed this onto the next line when I view the source code.

```
border-width: 0px; border-style: s
olid;"
```

Can anyone suggest any reason for this with Gmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that because Gmail don't support external or inline style sheet 
from my experience you need to use only the style attribute
don't use inline or external styles, and put all your styles in the style attribute

e.g : <div style='border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;"'>